# readfile() corrupting file over output

Tags: php, readfile

I am using the following code, to access a file which exists

```
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

It downloads fine, but when opening the image viewer is refusing to open stating its not a gif file. Is

Comment: Is that dangling "Is" part of an unfinished sentence?

Comment: Is the source file 'monkey.gif' a GIF image, in the first place? Can you open it using an image viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a print elsewhere in the code so when it was forcing the download it was corrupted. Removing the print worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the Content-Type to 'image/gif'

Comment: The code in the question is copied from the PHP documentation page of function [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). It is provided as an example of how to force the browser to download the file (instead of displaying it).

Comment: O. Then it must be the 'monkey.gif' file's problem.